# I'm taking payment with Braintree. When can I ship the goods?

Tags: php, braintree

The simplified diagram [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/transactions/php#status) shows that payment could still be voided before the moment of settlement, **when** and **how** can I be sure that the payment is complete?

I was hoping to sumbit for settlement at the moment of despatch...

Comment: wah. Thanks for the downvotes. Can you let me know why and I'll delete the question if it's not relevant.

Comment: Voids are initiated by you. If you don't want it voided, don't submit a void.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz... So once authorized, it's guaranteed? (as long I settle it, of course).

Comment: Well, they could issue a chargeback months later (4-6 months is the typical limit on that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just automatically submit it for settlement.

When creating a transaction, use the `options.submitForSettlement` option.

More information [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/transactions/php#settlement)

Comment: I don't want to submit for settlement because a stock issue might prevent me from being able to fulfil the option, in which case I incur costly chargeback fees. (Sorry, my original question stated this but I think I was getting downvotes for verbosity, so I edited). 

Thanks for the response though - it may be valid for someone else!

Comment: Ok, so I'm confused. It turns out I can refund the payment for a very small fee. So what is the purpose/meaning of this line in the [docs](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/get-started/transaction-life-cycle) **Some merchants that ship physical goods wait to submit for settlement until after the product has shipped in order to reduce chargebacks**, I wonder!